# Grouping in loop

Tags: sql-server

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnCalTotalOvertime] 
    (@empCode INT, 
     @StartDate DATETIME, 
     @EndDate DATETIME) 
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE  @Result INT = '0'

    WHILE @StartDate < @EndDate
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Result = @Result+SUM(ISNULL(CAST(LTRIM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, [dbo].[fnGetOTDuration](CAST (@empCode AS NVARCHAR), @StartDate))) AS INT), 0))

        SET @StartDate = @StartDate + 1;
    END;

    RETURN @Result
END
```

I have this function that loops around in given dates and calculates total Sum of the overtime. Now there are 3 types of Overtimes OffDay, Public Holiday and working Day with different rates. This function loops and calculate total hours of dates regardless what type that is so it is not working when trying to calculate amount. I want it to group by but it's not letting me. I have another function which is getting the type of the day but when I use that in group by it gives an error.

I tried this way...

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnCalTotalOvertime] 
    (@empCode INT, 
     @StartDate DATETIME, 
     @EndDate DATETIME) 
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE  @Result INT = '0'

    WHILE @StartDate < @EndDate
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Result = @Result+SUM(ISNULL(CAST(LTRIM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, [dbo].[fnGetOTDuration](CAST (@empCode AS NVARCHAR), @StartDate))) AS INT), 0))
       GROUP BY [dbo].[fnGetDayType] (@StartDate, @empCode) 

       SET @StartDate = @StartDate + 1;
    END;

    RETURN @Result
END
```

Any guidance ?

Comment: How will a different rate affect the overtime duration?

Comment: @WolfgangKais Not duration but calculation.

Comment: Your function seems to calculate a total duration, so how would a calculation with different rates be useful in this function?